# /usr/bin/ruby vs. rvm

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

After going through the effort of finally [purging distro ruby packages](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) from my Ubuntu development sandbox to replace with the highly recommended rvm, I must be misunderstanding something fundamental:

I don't want to have to change all the shebang lines in all my .rb source files from

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

into **/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby** nor anything version-specific.

My source files *need* to remain constant with their counterparts on the production servers using the system default ruby binaries (not rvm).

Any suggestions to keep universal code consistency?  Should I be switching the shebangs, once and for evermore, to something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

or (despite [what that link's site says](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/default/)) is there some clean way for rvm to hook into /usr/bin/ruby assuming all conflicting .deb packages had been removed?  Not to mention, how to get other .deb packages dependent on the presence of ruby+libs to recognize the non-distro ruby...but that might be a separate issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

the only sane way to go is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

it will always use current selected ruby in the environment, not depending on any tool

Answer (score 2):

Using the [env(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) shebang adds a level of complexity and a set of security concerns, but it is a commonly employed solution. One problem is that it does *not* wire the interpreter but makes it specific to per-user PATH values.

You could replace `/usr/bin/ruby` with a symbolic link. On modern linux, recursive shebang will work and /usr/bin/ruby could be a script like:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 exec /some/other/ruby "$@"
```

Comment: using scripts in shebang is only supported on linux 2.6.20+ not on OSX, and the link assumes you will have to change ruby for the whole system to run this script - might be not acceptable solution

Comment: Hmm, yes, recursive shebang is problematic.

Comment: This worked nice for me, I had some scripts running from cron and it was convenient to have it remain the same